# Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable' in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, datatables

I have a page that uses DataTables and works perfectly fine in every browser except Internet Explorer (all versions from 7-10 give the error). The error is as in the title `Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable'`. The problem has been observed on multiple systems, I am testing it on a Virtual Box instance of Win7. The error is getting thrown on the first line after the ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var invoiceTable = $('#invoiceTable').dataTable( {
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 50,   // Set default of 50 rows
        "bSort": false
    })
```

The datatables library is loaded above that with

```
<script src="https:////cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Anyone know what can cause IE to throw this error with DataTables?

Comment: Are you sure the external script is loading?  Check the console.

Comment: There's no error message in the console besides the one I mentioned above. Unless IE doesn't report that in the console, it's loading fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```